# How to get rid of TLE?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I solved the following [challenge](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/magician-and-chocolates/) by brute-force:

> Given N bags, each bag contains Ai chocolates. There is a kid and a
>   magician. In one unit of time, kid chooses a random bag i, eats Ai
>   chocolates, then the magician fills the ith bag with floor(Ai/2)
>   chocolates.
>
> Given Ai for 1 <= i <= N, find the maximum number of chocolates kid
>   can eat in K units of time.
>
> For example,
>
> K = 3 N = 2 A = 6 5
>
> Return: 14
>
> At t = 1 kid eats 6 chocolates from bag 0, and the bag gets filled by
>   3 chocolates At t = 2 kid eats 5 chocolates from bag 1, and the bag
>   gets filled by 2 chocolates At t = 3 kid eats 3 chocolates from bag 0,
>   and the bag gets filled by 1 chocolate so, total number of chocolates
>   eaten: 6 + 5 + 3 = 14
>
> Note: Return your answer modulo 10^9+7

First I took the array in the vector pair which first element is the value and 2nd element is index. then I find the max value from the vector and also change that value.

Unfortunately, that takes too long.
Is there a better way?

```
int Solution::nchoc(int A, vector<int> &B) {
   vector<pair<int, int> >vc;

    for(int i=0; i<B.size(); i++)
    {
        vc.push_back(make_pair(B[i],i));
    }

    int sum=0;

    while(A>0)
    {
        pair<int,int> x=*max_element(vc.begin(),vc.end());

        int x1=x.first;
        vc[x.second].first= (int) vc[x.second].first/2;

        sum=((sum%1000000007)+(x1%1000000007))%1000000007;

        A--;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: If kids eat that much chocolate they are at risk of developing diabetes.

Comment: @RawN An inelegant request for a better algorithm, which is the reason I added the tag.

Comment: @Deduplicator That was very nice of you. Kudos for having the patience to go through that wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm has order O(N*K), because you check every bag for every step.

Instead, use a heap of A<sub>i</sub>, and always take the top-element for an algorithm of order O(K*log N).

You want `push_heap`, `pop_heap` and `make_heap` from [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).